# Coin Change (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We usually the following recurrence relation for the coin change problem:
(`P` is the total money for which we need change and `d_i` is the coin available)
[image]

But can't we make it like this:
(`V` is the given sorted set of coins available, `i` and `j` are its subscripts with `Vj` being the highest value coin given)

```
C[p,Vi,j] = C[p,Vi,j-1]     if Vj > p
          = C[p-Vj,Vi,j] + 1  if Vj <=p
```

Is there anything wrong with what I wrote? Though the solution is not dynamic but isn't it more efficient?

Comment: Doesn't this assume that V will contain a coin worth 1 unit. What if P = 7 and V = [3, 2], you'd end up getting 2 value 3 coins and then error out instead of 1 value 3 coin and 2 value 2 coins.

Comment: @LastCoder I got your point. The above solution is assuming that we have a coin worth 1 unit. Now next thing is if we are given coin worth 1 unit, then the above be more efficient solution then the dynamic solution, right?

Comment: Where do you use `Vi` in your formula?

Comment: @IVlad: The set is actually Vi to Vj. So when I write Vi,j then i assume that the set V contains all the elements from Vi to Vj. When I write Vi,j-1 then I assume that the set V contains all the elements form Vi to Vj-1 which means that last coin is excluded form the coins set.

Comment: That is a very confusing notation, because you also use just `Vj` and you use commas to separate both indices and function parameters. I suggest using square brackets to make it clearer, I read your formula as `C[p,(Vi),(j-1)]; C[(p-Vj),(Vi),(j)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `P = 6, V = {4, 3, 1}`. You would pick `4, 1, 1` instead of `3, 3`, so `3` coins instead of the optimal `2`.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is similar to the greedy algorithm that works only under certain conditions. (See - [How to tell if greedy algorithm suffices for finding minimum coin change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025076/how-to-tell-if-greedy-algorithm-suffices-for-the-minimum-coin-change-problem#6031625)).

Also,  in your version you aren't actually using `Vi` within the recurrence, so it's just a waste of memory